# Documentation for wxPython 2.4?

Tags: python, documentation, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm desperately looking for the documentation of this rather old version of wxpython. I found the documentation for the C++ version of the library, but some APIs differ and I'd really like to have documentation that really corresponds to the library I'm using.

Could you point me to it? (assuming it exists!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find demo and source files (they include docs) here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.4.2.4/

There are also Docs:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.4.2.4/wxPythonDocs-2.4.2.4.tar.gz/download

Comment: This is the documentation that I already have, and it lacks some info. For example, it doesn't describe wxSizer.Insert which is available from wxPython. I'm starting to think that what I'm looking for doesn't exist, plain and simple.

Comment: Doc is made off python __docs__ using epydoc so if it's not there you will not find it. Anyway I pointed to what you asked...

Comment: Why would you use such an old version of wx anyway? By the way, sometimes to need to navigate up the inheritance tree to see all the methods of a child. This page shows the Insert info: http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sizer-class.html (for the current version of wxPython)

Comment: Mike is right, I took it for granted

Comment: Why use it? Because it's what we use at work. No, it's not in the inheritance tree in the documentation for my version.